# ClassCastException com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl

Tags: json, jakarta-ee, jersey, classcastexception

I am getting a ClassCastException. I wonder what I am doing wrong here. Doing a `(RegistrationRequest)(element.getValue())` should have worked. I know that `(RegistrationRequest)element.getValue()` may not have.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey REST Service] in context with path [/mCruiseOnCarPool4All] threw exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to com.mcruiseon.common.message.request.RegistrationRequest
```

Server Post method, notice the JAXBElement in the method signature. I am typecasting it `clientSession.waitAndGetResponse((RegistrationRequest)(element.getValue())) ;`. This is the line number where I am getting the exception.

```
@POST
@Path ("Request")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response post(JAXBElement<Object> element) {
    AMessageStrategy response ;
    try {
        clientSession = new ClientSession(God.mCruiseOnServer) ;
    } catch (InvalidServerDNSorIPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.serverError().build() ;
    }
    sessionKey = sessionManager.setClientSession(clientSession) ;
    clientSession.setSessionKey(sessionKey) ;

    clientSession.getSendQueue().sendRequest((RegistrationRequest)(element.getValue()));                
    try {
        response = clientSession.waitAndGetResponse((RegistrationRequest)(element.getValue())) ;
    } catch (WaitedLongEnoughException e) {
        return Response.serverError().build() ;
    } catch (UnableToResolveResponseException e) {
        return Response.serverError().build() ;
    }   
    return Response.ok(response).build();
}
```

The client side is a junit test case, relevant part of code is

```
ClientIdentityConcrete clientIdentity = new ClientIdentityConcrete("username", "password", "secretkey") ;
RegistrationRequest register = new RegistrationRequest(clientIdentity);
String jsonStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(clientIdentity);
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8081/mCruiseOnCarPool4All/carpool4all/Registration/Request");
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonStr);
se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
request.setEntity(se);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was on the client side, junit test case. I was not creating a Json object for with register, instead I am createing the object using clientIdentity. Notice the `writeValueAsString`. I also modified my entire client to actually use the JSON client apis, rather than legacy http. Isn't work as yet, I am getting another exception. But that's a different question.

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(config);
        WebResource service = client.resource(UriBuilder.fromUri(
                "http://localhost:8081/mCruiseOnCarPool4All").build());

        ClientIdentityConcrete clientIdentity = new ClientIdentityConcrete("username", "password", "secretkey");
        RegistrationRequest register = new RegistrationRequest(clientIdentity);
        AMessageStrategy response = service.path("carpool4all").path("Registration").path("Request")
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(RegistrationRequest.class, register);
        assertNotNull(response) ;
        assertNotNull(((RegistrationResponse)response).getIdentityHash()) ;
```